# iOS UITableView loose content after "received memory warning" message

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, didreceivememorywarning

(originally i posted this on `Apple Developer Network` and got no response in four days, so i am copy/pasting here)

ARC is enabled.

In my class i have an `UITableViewController` property,

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController* tableViewControllerSectionMenu;`

which is used to hold table view for `UIPopoverController`.

This code creates `UITableViewController` and sets delagate and data source in `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.tableViewControllerSectionMenu = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableViewControllerSectionMenu.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
self.tableViewControllerSectionMenu.tableView.delegate = self;
```

This works fine until memory warning occur.

After that the table is blank.

I tried putting `reloadData` at place where popover is invoked but that changes nothing.

Does somebody know why this is happening and how to remedy this?

By googling i have found several solutions and none have worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I think your data is cleaned when the memory warning is received. Did you implement either `didReceiveMemoryWarning` or `viewDidUnload` by any chance?

Comment: Yes i have implemented `didReceiveMemoryWarning` but view controller of the main view, but it only has `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`. Just to clarify, i dont have custom class for `tableViewControllerSectionMenu`. I dont see how these two things can be useful here, without custom view controller class, can you please clarify?

Comment: And yes, data gets cleaned from that table view controller, but my data source is still there.

Comment: Then I have no clue... sorry

Answer (score 0):

When memory warning message is received, all views not currently visible on screen are purged. They are supposed to be recreated later when needed.

To recreate them means also to attach delegate and data source again. Since memory warning was received while in ViewController X, and it's view was on screen, my table view got purged.

But as i wasn't moving from X, delegate and data source were not attached again, as that was done in `viewDidLoad`.

To evade getting back one step from X, i created a new class for my table view where in `viewDidLoad` i attached delegate and data source.